# Why does volley has duplicated Cookie in request header?

Tags: cookies, android-volley

I define a volley request as follows, but sometimes I cannot get the right data from server(after I just logged in), so I use Fiddler to watch the request, It SEEMS THAT there are two Cookie section in the request header, so the server treat it as guest identity and the wrong data are returned. so why
two Cookie sections there?

```
public class JsonArrayPostRequestWithCookie extends Request<JSONArray> {
    private static final String TAG = "tag";
    public static final String Cookie = "Cookie";
    private Map<String, String> mMap;
    private Response.Listener<JSONArray> mListener;
    private Map<String, String> mSendHeader=new HashMap<String, String>();

    public JsonArrayPostRequestWithCookie(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Map<String, String> map, String cookie) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        mMap = map;
        setSendCookie(cookie);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mMap;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString =
                    new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

            return Response.success(jsonarray,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONArray response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();
        if (headers == null
                || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
                headers = mSendHeader;
        }else{
                headers.remove(Cookie);
                headers.putAll(mSendHeader);
        }
        return headers;
    }

    private void setSendCookie(String cookie){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(cookie)){
            return;
        }
        mSendHeader.put(Cookie, cookie);
    }
}
```

the request header like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghy2X.png), It is wierd, why two same Cookie section here?

PS: here is how I use it:

```
`       map.put("vid", "1");
        map.put("parent", "0");
        map.put("maxdepth", "3");
        String cookie = "";
        if(Constants.logged){
            cookie = StringUtil.getSessionMsg();
        }
        JsonArrayPostRequestWithCookie getReq = new JsonArrayPostRequestWithCookie(RequestUrlProvider.ALL_MSG_PATH, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        }, map, cookie);
        getReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, 1.0f));
        getReq.setShouldCache(false);
        NYiportalApplication.mReqQue.add(getReq);
```

Comment: Try setting breakpoint at `headers.putAll(mSendHeader);`, then debug and check the value of both `headers` and `mSendHeader`. Or use Log.i(...) then check logcat output

Comment: @BNK, I already did that. thanks. `mSendHeader` just has one Cookie there

Comment: How about `headers` ? Pls post the code how you called `JsonArrayPostRequestWithCookie` request

Comment: @BNK, I updated the question.  I said it is wierd because:  If I restart my app after logged, it will be auto relogged, in this situation, I can get the right data.  If my app started as guest, then I logged in manually, then the problem comes out.

Comment: Try using like `copy = new HashMap<String, String>(org);` instead of putAll

Comment: But actually the putAll are not reached, instaed `headers = mSendHeader;` is executed.

Comment: Ok, instead of that, try "headers = new HashMap<String, String>(mSendHeader);" too

Comment: do you set custom httpStack ?

Comment: @djodjo  no, I will try.  But would you pls tell me how to do that?  It seems that using `getHeaders()` has side effects

Comment: @BNK, OK, I will try that

Comment: @BNK  no lucky.  I tried my app in different phones, It is always OK on some phones, and It is always WRONG on others, so I am not sure it is devices' problem or volley's, so wierd

Comment: im just asking not suggesting :) because it cam have side effects. can you please add how you create the mReqQue. also on what android version are u experiencing this

Comment: @djodjo `mReqQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);`   and the device is Motorola Nexus 6 Android 5.1.1, API 22

Comment: @djodjo My app has auto relogin function, when the bug comes out, if I restart the app, then I can get the data I want, the same code are executed, so I said it is wierd